# r - googleVis - gvisGeoMap - I cannot plot the map generated by gvisGeoMap

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm trying to plot a map of Spain by province but it's not possible to plot it

```
RegionPopular<-data.frame(
  Region=c('ES-IB', 'ES-CT', 'ES-EX')
  ,Popular=c(100,200,300)
)

G3 <- gvisGeoMap(RegionPopular, locationvar='Region', numvar='Popular',
                 options=list(region="ES", dataMode="regions",
                              width=600, height=400))
plot(G3)
```

Comment: FYI https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/42